# Shrink UICollectionView reusable header height when hiding subviews or changing subview heights

Tags: swift, autolayout, constraints

I have a `UICollectionView` with a reusable header on top which contains two views. One is another `collectionView` and under it a `filtersView`.

This is how I display the header and control its layout dynamically.

```
let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout
if let flowLayout = layout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
   flowLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: self.collectionView.frame.size.width, height: 70)
}
```

Now when I hide or change `filtersView` height constant the `collectionView` is filling up the whole `headerView`.

What I need is to shrink the `headerView` itself.

I have top, bottom, leading and trailing and constant height constraints for `collectionView` in the `headerView` and also the same for the `filtersView` that is underneath the `collectionView`

Tried playing with priorities and heights programmatically a lot but never succeeded to shrink the `headerView` to be same height of `collectionView` when `filtersView` is hidden or its height is equal to 0.

For demonstration purposes I added a cyan background color to the `collectionView` and a dark gray color for the whole `headerView` background.

1st Image `filterView` height = 50

[image]

2nd Image `filterView` height = 0
[image]

Comment: What are the constraints that you have for your view at the moment?  How are you establishing those constraints (in code, or in Interface Builder)?

Comment: @ScottThompson Established in Interface Builder and have references of them in the code to change their constants.

Comment: @ScottThompson Constraints for collection view Top & sides to superview bottom to filters view top and constant fixed height. Constraints for filters view Top to collection view bottom and sides to superview and bottom to superview.